# 301 Redirect only working on Refresh

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Hi sorry if the answer is somewhere else but I did search and didn't run across this problem. I want to use a 301 to redirect www to non-www and this is the code I'm using.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It kinda of works.. If you type in www.exaple.com it doesn't work but if you refresh the page THEN it does work.

Anyone know whats going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rule works fine, your issue is using `R=301` (permanent redirect) which tells browsers to cache redirected URLs aggressively.

When you force refresh in browser then only browser request goes to web server otherwise it serves the content from its cache.

**As a general practice one should avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing out `mod_rewrite` rules.**

Comment: I've cleared my cache/history/settings multiple times yet it continues with this problem? My cache is only one day long (roughly) so changes renew often enough. What would code would you suggest using then?

Comment: Change 301 to 302 for testing and then clear your browser cache.

Comment: Well I changed nothing and woke up today and it is working perfectly now. Hopefully it stays this way. Thanks guys!

Comment: Yes I guess that was expected behavior with R=301